# Rotate screen at startup in Linux/Lakka

Tags: linux, rotation

I'm trying to rotate my entire screen at startup on Lakka (a Linux based gaming OS). I'm rather new to using Linux, so I don't know how to do this. 
I have tried using the following method to attempt rotation:

```
mount -o remount,rw /flash
nano /flash/extlinux.conf
```

I then add "fbcon=rotate_all:2" to the end of that file, then remount like so:

```
mount -o remount,ro /flash
```

Unfortunately, it's not doing anything. I must be missing something here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as required for Stackoverflow. Your question may be appropriate on other sites such as [Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help first before posting.

Comment: To rotate the screen you should use `xranrdr -o inverted` (and `xrandr -o normal` to get it back).  But you're doing something with filesystems there, did you really mean `screen`?  Also, as kaylum suggests, [u&l](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for this.

Answer (score 0):

A common tool for monitor manipulation in Linux is `xrandr`. From a quick search around, it seems as if you can rotate a specified screen with this tool.

Running `xrandr --query` will list connected devices that you can reference. After finding the name for your monitor, you can run this command to rotate it.

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --rotate left
```

This is just an example of course, the `HDMI1` is the name of your screen, and you can also replace `left` with something else in order to get the correct rotation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I actually tried using xrandr, but the system I'd made using KMS and DRM, so that unfortunately won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still struggling with this, I have managed to get this working with RPi4.aarch64-4.3 on a raspbery pi 4

None of the options in `config.txt` seem to work, including `display_rotate`, `lcd_rotate` or `display_lcd_rotate` -- I've seen all three mentioned elsewhere which took a bit of hacking to figure out.

What DID work, however, was changing my cmdline.txt to this:

`boot=UUID=1601-4956 disk=UUID=cf389dbc-3522-4293-8a16-7457c2d08517 video=DSI-1:800x480@60,rotate=180 quiet`

Your boot and disk entries may be different, so you just want to add the `video=DSI-1:800x480@60,rotate=180` bit in.

I hope this helps save someone a bit of time!